# How to get jsdoc to work with django template tags?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, documentation, jsdoc

I have js files with {% %} template tags in them, which causes jsdoc to fail with

```
ERROR: Unable to parse <path>: Unexpected token
```

Is there any way to get django template tags to work with jsdoc or any other javascript doc generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing the javascript and django's template language is inherently bad, try to avoid that. In the case of jsdoc I think that you need to look into its interpolation which would be fairly complex task.

The other solution that I can think of is to switch the dafault django template language with jinja2. And then you can set there something like these: https://gist.github.com/lost-theory/3925738 but you might encounter an error again.

What I would do is this, put constants in the place of the variables and then generate the docs, after that simply put back the django's variables.